# How do I know if I installed some software on my Mac, or if it is part of the OS?

Tags: macos

I have had my Mac for almost three years now, and I it is hard for me to remember which software was installed by me and which one is part of the operating system.

For example, I want to upgrade node.js, and the current version installed is at `/usr/local/bin/node`. Since it is under `/usr`, that makes me think it was installed by me, and it is safe to remove. Is that right?

I know it is recommended to use a package managers such as Homebrew, but I didn't know that before, and I have installed many applications without a package manager for years.

Also, my mac has only 249 GB of space, and it has about 14% of space left. At this point, I do not want to leave old versions of software behind that I do not need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful link found via Google
(https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/app-installation-history-mac-os-x/) 
Taken from that site as follows :

> To find your app installation history in OS X, head to the System Information window (f.k.a. System Profiler). You can get there by clicking on the Apple icon in the Menu Bar, holding the Option key, and selecting System Information, or you can launch the System Information app located in Macintosh HD/Applications/Utilities/.
>
> System Information provides a wealth of information about your Mac and operating system, including important details such as your Mac’s serial number and specific model identifier, memory type and configuration, attached USB and Thunderbolt devices, and the capabilities of your network interface. What we’re interested in, however, is Software.
>
> In the list of categories on the left of the System Information window, find Installations under the Software section. This window displays a complete list of all software currently installed on your Mac, including any updates.

Any software that didn't ship with the Mac, would have "Source" listed as "3rd party" 
Hope this helps!